# Late JSON Response with Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

I am working on my first project using backbone.js. It should be a frontend to a Play! App with a JSON interface. Here's a part of my JS code

```
var api = 'http://localhost:9001/api'

// Models
var Node = Backbone.Model.extend();

// Collections
var Nodes = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Nodes,
  url: api + '/nodes',
});

// Views NODE
var NodeView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: $("#son_node_elements"),
  render: function(){
    var source = $("#son_node_item_templ").html();
    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
    $(this.el).append(template(this.model.toJSON()));
    return this;
  }
});

var NodeListView = Backbone.View.extend({

  initialize: function(){
    _.bindAll(this, "render");
    this.collection = new Nodes();
    this.collection.bind("change",this.render);
    this.collection.fetch();
    this.render();
  },

  render: function(){
    _(this.collection.models).each(function(item){ 
      var nodeView = new NodeView({model: item});
      $(this.el).append(nodeView.render().el);
    }, this);   
  }
});

Nodes = new NodeListView({el:$('#son_nodes')});
```

My Problem is that when `this.render()` is called, `this.collection.fetch()` is still not done and `this.collection` does not contain anithing to render. All works fine when I set a breakpoint at `this.render()` (for example using firebug), so `this.render()` is not called immediately. I get exactly the same result when I access a local JSON file instead of the api of my app. Any suggestions how to handle this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fetch can also be called from outside view, so let the view listen for that instead:

`this.collection.bind("reset",this.render);`

Reset event will be triggered on every call to `this.collection.fetch();`

And finally, skip `this.render();`  Don't call this yourself, since reset event handler do this for you.

Comment: What happens with this when an error occurs during this.collection.fetch()?

Comment: you can pass the success and error functions to the fetch function

Answer (score 2):

You need to call "render" inside the "success" callback for your "fetch()":

```
this.collection.fetch({
  success: function(col) {
    col.render();
  }
});
```

That defers the rendering until the collection fetching is complete. It's all asynchronous.

**Caveat:** I barely know anything about Backbone in particular, but something along these lines is definitely your problem.  In other words, there may be other things to worry about that I haven't mentioned (because I don't know what they are :-).

Comment: +1. `.fetch` is an asynchronous method--the script will chug on to the next line before the request is back, and things like `.render` that depend on that data being there will fail. Rendering needs to happen in the success handler on the fetch method.

Comment: Thanks Pointy, thats exactly my problem. The the `col.render()` part does now work... what kind of object is `col` that is passed to the function?

Comment: @sontags it's the collection object itself. In this case it was convenient to use it, because otherwise I'd have had to have saved `this.collection` in a temp. variable so that the handler could get at it. The "success" function is (apparently) passed the collection itself plus the raw server response; I left out the second argument because I have no idea really what it's supposed to look like, and in your example it didn't seem interesting anyway.